# Change Servlet code into Spring Boot framework

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I currently have an apache tomcat server that uses servlets to display .csv data in a table format, it's not very complicated.
I want to try and convert my current setup to Spring Boot as a way to learn Spring Boot.

My current code gets the directory of where the files are stored and makes a list of files, then uses CSVReader to read each csv file.

Essentially I want to read in data from a file and display it in a table. Currently using .csv but happy to change the format.

I can't wrap my head around a way of doing this without creating a similar servlet as my previous one. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I don't think my original design has layered logic either which might need some redesign to work with this framework.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.File;
import java.time.LocalDate;

import com.opencsv.CSVReader;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class TonerLevels
 */
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/TonerLevels", "/"})
public class TonerLevels extends HttpServlet {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        // Do required initialization
     }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        
        out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/js/bootstrap.bundle.js\"></script>\n");
        out.println("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"/css/bootstrap.css\"></link>\n");
        out.println("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"/css/style.css\"></link>\n");
        out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/js/script.js\"></script>\n");

        File[] fileList = fileList();       

        String title = "KHS Printers";
        String docType =
            "<!doctype html public \"-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 " + "transitional//en\">\n";
        String nav = "<nav data-bs-theme=\"dark\" class=\"navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary\">\r\n"+
             "  <div class=\"container-fluid\">\r\n"+
             "    <a class=\"navbar-brand\" >KHS Printers</a>\r\n"+
             "    <button class=\"navbar-toggler\" type=\"button\" data-bs-toggle=\"collapse\" data-bs-target=\"#navbarSupportedContent\" aria-controls=\"navbarSupportedContent\" aria-expanded=\"false\" aria-label=\"Toggle navigation\">\r\n"+
             "      <span class=\"navbar-toggler-icon\"></span>\r\n"+
             "    </button>\r\n"+
             "    <div class=\"collapse navbar-collapse\" id=\"navbarSupportedContent\">\r\n"+
             "      <ul class=\"navbar-nav nav-pills me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0\">\r\n"+
             "        <li class=\"nav-item\">\r\n"+
             "          <a class=\"nav-link active\" aria-current=\"page\" href=\"/TonerLevels\">Toner Levels</a>\r\n"+
             "        </li>\r\n"+
             "        <li class=\"nav-item\">\r\n"+
             "          <a class=\"nav-link\" href=\"/MonoPrints\">Mono Prints</a>\r\n"+
             "        </li>\r\n"+
             "    <li class=\"nav-item\">\r\n"+
             "          <a class=\"nav-link\" href=\"/MonoCopies\">Mono Copies</a>\r\n"+
             "        </li>\r\n"+
             "    <li class=\"nav-item\">\r\n"+
             "          <a class=\"nav-link\" href=\"/ColourPrints\">Colour Prints</a>\r\n"+
             "        </li>\r\n"+
             "    <li class=\"nav-item\">\r\n"+
             "          <a class=\"nav-link\" href=\"/ColourCopies\">Colour Copies</a>\r\n"+
             "        </li>\r\n"+
             "    <li class=\"nav-item dropdown\">\r\n"+
                 "      <a class=\"nav-link dropdown-toggle\" data-bs-toggle=\"dropdown\" href=\"#\" role=\"button\" aria-expanded=\"false\">Monthly Reports</a>\r\n"+
             "      <ul class=\"dropdown-menu\">\r\n"+
             "      <form action=\"Monthly\" method=\"post\">\r\n";
            if(fileList.length > 0){
                for(int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++){
                    String name = fileList[i].getName();
                    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(name.substring(0,name.length()-4));
                    String month = date.getMonth().minus(1).toString();
                    String year = Integer.toString(date.getYear());
                    nav+="<li><button type=\"submit\" class=\"dropdown-item\" name=\"report\" value=\""+name+"\" href=\"/Monthly\">"+month+" "+year+"</button></li>\r\n";
                }
            }
            nav+=""+    
             "      </form>\r\n"+   
                 "      </ul>\r\n"+
             "    </li>\r\n"+
             "      </ul>\r\n"+
             "    </div>\r\n"+
             "  </div>\r\n"+
             "</nav>\r\n";
        String path = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(".").getPath();
        path = path.replaceAll("%20", " ");
        try { 
            FileReader filereader = new FileReader(path+"printers/printers.csv");
            CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(filereader);
            String[] nextRecord;

            out.println(docType +
                "<html>\n" +
                    "<head><title>" + title + "</title>\n" +
                    "</head>\n" +
                    "<body onload=\"sortTable()\">\n" +
                        nav +               
                        "<table class=\"table table-dark table-hover\">\n");
                        int i = 0;
                        String regex = "^((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1\\d|[1-9]|)\\d)\\.?\\b){4}$";
                        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

                        while ((nextRecord = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {   
                            if (i==0){
                                out.println("<thead>\n");
                                out.println("<tr>\n");
                                for (String cell : nextRecord) {
                                    if("Black".equals(cell) || "Yellow".equals(cell) || "Magenta".equals(cell) || "Cyan".equals(cell) || "K1".equals(cell) || "K2".equals(cell)){
                                        out.println("<th>" + cell + " %</th>\n");
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        out.println("<th>" + cell + "</th>\n");
                                    }
                                }
                                out.println();
                                out.println("</tr>\n");
                                out.println("</thead>\n");
                                out.println("<tbody class=\"table-group-divider\">\n");
                            }
                            else{
                                out.println("<tr>\n");
                                for (String cell : nextRecord) {
                                    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(cell);
                                    if(matcher.matches()){
                                        out.println("<td><a href=\"http://"+cell+"\"target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener noreferrer\">"+ cell +"</a></td>\n");
                                    }
                                    else if(cell.matches("-?(0|[1-9]\\d*)")){
                                        out.println("<td>" + Integer.parseInt(cell) + "</td>\n");
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        out.println("<td>" + cell + "</td>\n");
                                    }
                                }
                                out.println();
                                out.println("</tr>\n");
                            }
                            i++;
                        }
                        out.println("</tbody>\n");
                        out.println("</table>\n" +
                    "</body>\n" +
                "</html>\n"
                );
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

    private File[] fileList(){
        //get list of files in /printers/reports
        File catalinaBase = new File( System.getProperty( "catalina.base" ) ).getAbsoluteFile();
        File f = new File( catalinaBase, "/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/printers/reports");
        File[] fileList = new File[0];
        if(f.isDirectory()) {
            fileList = f.listFiles();
            if(fileList.length > 0) {
                Arrays.sort(fileList, Collections.reverseOrder());
            }
        }
        return fileList;
    }

}
```

Comment: By the way, you might want to use [text blocks](https://openjdk.org/jeps/378) to manage that HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up saving my printer data as a json and using spring boot / react.
Steps i took:

- Deserialize json into list of Printer objects (printer class i made) with jackson
- Use list of Printer objects for rest api (built in functionality of spring boot)
- In react use axios to get the api (json containing my printers) and map them to a Printer type in react
- Use JSX and html in react to format website with bootstrap

So essentially spring boot does all the work and exposes what i want to show through api's then react will display the data.